# How to translate this code from AVR into STM32

Tags: c, stm32, avr, stm32cubeide

I am trying to rewrite the code from AVR to STM32. How to translate this code into STM32?

```
#define READ_IO     PIND & (1 << PD4)
volatile unsigned char data_in = 0;
data_in = (READ_IO) >> PD4;
```

I use STM32CubeIDE

Comment: This is reading an IO pin. Find the IO pin in the STM32 you want to map to this and then read it into `data_in` variable. Actually there's not much to it we can help since the key point here is to define which is the equivalent pin for your application, and this is essentially arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming pin4 on port D.

```
data_in = !!(GPIOD -> IDR & (1 << 4));
```